# JSON add node to an existing JObject

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to add a new node to an existing `JSON` `JObject`, but when I add it does not format correctly.  It adds quotes around the entire node, and \ are put in place.

Background:
I am loading a `JSON` file, doing some logic then adding a node back in.  Figured I can do it like this:

```
mainJson.Add("NewNode", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject));
File.WriteAllText("myfile.json", mainJson.ToString());
```

Problem is that this is the result:

```
{
"JSONFile": [
  {
    "More": "Nodes",
    "InThe": "File"
  }
],
"Customers": "{\"FirstName\":\"Mike\",\"LastName\":\"Smith\"},{\"FirstName\":\"Jane\",\"LastName\":\"Doe\"}",
}
```

I know that my JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject) is working if I do this:

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject);
File.WriteAllText("myfile2.json" json);
```

The result is this:

```
[
  {
    "FirstName": "Mike",
    "LastName": "Smith"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Jane",
    "LastName": "Doe"
  }
]
```

What am I missing?

**edit:**
Following @Swagata Prateek comment of;

```
mainJson.Add("Customers",JObject.FromObject(MyObject));
```

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll
>
> Additional information: Object serialized to Array. JObject instance expected.

I should note that MyObject is actual `ObservableCollection` if that makes a difference

Comment: When you invoke `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject)` , `MyObject` here is serialized as a string, thus the `NewNode` here is presenting itself as a string quoted. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you kindly try with this?

```
mainJson.Add("NewNode", JObject.FromObject(MyObject));
File.WriteAllText("myfile.json", mainJson.ToString());
```

When you are doing `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject)` it serializes `MyObject` and in the process you get a string out of it.

When you assign `mainJson.Add("NewNode", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyObject));` you're assigning a string to `NewNode`. Thus you get a quoted string that represents serialized `MyObject`

**Update**:

`JArray.FromObject` is the method you'd want to look for if you want to convert your collection to a JArray. In that case the segment would look something like

```
mainJson.Add("NewNode", JArray.FromObject(obsColl));
File.WriteAllText("myfile.json", mainJson.ToString());
```

Comment: A man chooses, a slave obeys!  anyways please look at the above edit.  This is returning an error.

Comment: Ooops. Sorry dude. Didnt know that was a collection. Hold on. Not sure i can type code segment properly through a phone

Answer (score 1):

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            JObject tempvar= JObject.Parse(@"{
  'CPU': 'Intel',
  'Drives': [
    'DVD read/writer',
    '500 gigabyte hard drive'
  ]
}");
            string cpu = (string)tempvar["CPU"];          // Intel
            string firstDrive = (string)tempvar["Drives"][0];   // DVD read/writer
IList<string> allDrives = tempvar["Drives"].Select(t => (string)t).ToList();
            // DVD read/writer
            // 500 gigabyte hard drive

            tempvar["Drives"][0].AddAfterSelf("new node");
//tempvar json with new node
        }
    }
}
```